# Exporting Hive Table to a S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, elastic-map-reduce, emr

I've created a Hive Table through an Elastic MapReduce interactive session and populated it from a CSV file like this:

```
CREATE TABLE csvimport(id BIGINT, time STRING, log STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t';

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '/home/hadoop/file.csv' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE csvimport;
```

I now want to store the Hive table in a S3 bucket so the table is preserved once I terminate the MapReduce instance.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Yes you have to export and import your data at the start and end of your hive session

To do this you need to create a table that is mapped onto S3 bucket and directory

```
CREATE TABLE csvexport (
  id BIGINT, time STRING, log STRING
  ) 
 row format delimited fields terminated by ',' 
 lines terminated by '\n' 
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION 's3n://bucket/directory/';
```

Insert data into s3 table and when the insert is complete the directory will have a csv file

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE csvexport 
 select id, time, log
 from csvimport;
```

Your table is now preserved and when you create a new hive instance you can reimport your data

Your table can be stored in a few different formats depending on where you want to use it.

Comment: the file in S3 is created without headers and with a random file name. is there a way to solve this problem? checked some of the posts on SO, couldn't find any relevant answers.

Comment: Same comment as above + how to fill the AWS credentials in there? I mean the ID and Secret keys. Thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Above Query needs to use EXTERNAL keyword, i.e:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE csvexport ( id BIGINT, time STRING, log STRING ) 
row format delimited fields terminated by ',' lines terminated by '\n' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 's3n://bucket/directory/';
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE csvexport select id, time, log from csvimport;
```

An another alternative is to use the query

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3n://bucket/directory/'  select id, time, log from csvimport;
```

the table is stored in the S3 directory with HIVE default delimiters.

Comment: This doesn't copy the header. is there a way to copy header also?

Comment: @MohammadAdnan did you find a way to copy header?

Comment: @MohammadAdnan did u find a way to copy the headers?

Answer (score 0):

If you could access aws console and have the "`Access Key Id`" and "`Secret Access Key`" for your account

You can try this too..

```
CREATE TABLE csvexport(id BIGINT, time STRING, log STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3n://"access id":"secret key"@bucket/folder/path';
```

Now insert the data as other stated above..

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE csvexport select id, time, log from csvimport;
```