# Why does Shark running on EC2 give me a "Wrong FS" error when writing data to S3

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, hive, shark-sql

I am running Shark/Spark (0.9.1) on Amazon EC2 using the supplied setup scripts. I am reading data out of S3 and then trying to write back a table into S3. The data can be read from S3 fine (so my credentials are correct) but when I try to write data to S3 I get the following error:

> 14/07/31 16:42:30 INFO scheduler.TaskSetManager: Loss was due to
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong FS:
>   s3n://id:key@shadoop/tmp/hive-root/hive_2014-07-31_16-39-29_825_6436105804053790400/_tmp.-ext-10000,
>   expected: hdfs://ecmachine.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000 [duplicate 3]

I've tried several different methods of writing out data/tables but they all produce the same error. This particular error is generated from a HQL query like:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY 's3n://id:key@shadoop/bucket' SELECT * FROM table;
```

Any ideas on why S3 is seen as a "wrong FS"?

Comment: I have also tried referencing the suggestions here to no avail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220837/how-to-add-partition-using-hive-by-a-specific-date

Answer (score 0):

`Wrong FS` normally means wrong hostname. Here is an SO post relating to setting the hostname:
[getting Wrong FS: file while running hive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561548/getting-wrong-fs-file-while-running-hive-query)

Here is a thread where another user solved this problem by adding entries to the `/etc/hosts` file on his server:
http://hadoop-common.472056.n3.nabble.com/Wrong-FS-td326744.html

---

However, after reading through your question several times it looks like your error is different. Your query is expecting to be written to hadoop FS, not S3. `expected: hdfs://ecmachine.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9000`. Perhaps you could export your query into a CSV and then import it into S3? See example here:

[Exporting Hive Table to a S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489487/exporting-hive-table-to-a-s3-bucket)

Comment: I can export, then import but that is a painful process - writing all of the files to a central machine from the HDFS and then uploading. From everything I read, Shark should be able to target S3 directly, but I can't seem to get any solutions as to why this isn't working. Thanks for the help though.